# How to echo dates in php for sitemap and google consumption

Tags: php, date, datetime, xml-sitemap

I am creating a sitemap page. How do I echo dates in this format

```
2020-06-14T00:21:32+00:00
```

Instead of

```
2020-06-14 21:32:00
```